# Can a specific property / field be restricted from JavaDocs generation?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, raml

I have a few Java classes containing one or more properties that I would like to exclude from the JavaDocs when they are generated.  I am using the 'maven-javadoc-plugin' and cannot find any documentation indicating that this is possible.

Is there a tag that can be applied in the POM, nor an annotation that can be placed on the actual property in the Java class, so that specific properties can be excluded?

I know that exclusions can be done at the **package** level using the `<excludePackageNames />` tag in the POM.  In addition, it appears that **specific classes** can be also restricted from the JavaDocs by using the `<sourceFileExcludes />` tag, so long as a `<sourcepath />` is also defined.

As an alternative, I am using RAML 1.0 to generate API documentation for this project, so does anyone know whether there is a RAML-specific exclusion that can be applied to prevent the documentation from being included?  Of course, the JavaDocs are generated separately from the RAML docs, so restricting individual class properties / fields on the RAML side (if possible) will still need a JavaDocs exclusion so that the Maven JavaDocs plugin also ignores them.

Thank you in advance!  Though I am expecting that the answer will be a negatory.

Comment: Could you explain, why you want to exclude a field from the JavaDoc of a class? Then it might be easier to help you.

Comment: @JFMeier Absolutely. Our team develops a suite of web services that are used by teams throughout our organization. We provide solutions that accelerate development and minimize code duplication.
    We built (and use) a security framework to filter access based on their rights. We provide API documentation (including JavaDocs) that describe the service(s) they are trying to call.
     We have a sensitive property most clients will not have access to. We want it excluded in our API docs. We don't want most clients to know that it is available; if they need it, they will have automatic access.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible solutions.

1. Write your own doclet.  API documentation (the HTML pages that describe Java classes) is generated from Javadoc comments by the [standard doclet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/standard-doclet.html).  That doclet is open-source code.  You could copy that doclet, change it slightly, and then run your modified version to create API documentation.
2. Define an annotation `@NotDocumented` that will appear in HTML documentation.  Write the annotation on the "secret" fields/methods of your class.  Create HTML API documentation normally.  Postprocess the HTML API documentation using a text processing tool like perl, awk, or sed to strip all references to `@NotDocumented` members.